# ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in ActiveAdmin only on newly created model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I have many models enabled for ActiveAdmin i.e. they are registered with ActiveAdmin with default behavior and working great.

When I generate new model and associated active_admin resource it shows following error

```
rails g model log body:text
rails g active_admin:resource log
rake db:migrate
```

And then try to create new log record from admin interface, it shows following error

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in Admin::LogsController#create

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: body
Rails.root: /Users/amitamb/sdtexty

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"wpTnR0B8qLphaxAyp/G9EuA4Gw+gZpwrdNjcYwvd3YY=",
 "log"=>{"body"=>"af"},
 "commit"=>"Create Log"}
Show session dump

Show env dump

Response

Headers:

None
```

Note: There is attr_accessible :body present in log model

Comment: can you post the log model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake.

I had added following code in `active_admin.rb` initializer

```
module ActiveAdmin
  class BaseController
    with_role :admin
  end
end
```

And I had forgotten to use `:as => :admin` in `attr_accessible`